# NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, ios8

I have a Core Data object (Order) which has a method to return an array of another Core Data object (OrderWaypoint).

```
func getOrderedWaypoints() -> [OrderWaypoint] {
    let nameDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "stop_number", ascending: true)
    let sorted: [OrderWaypoint] = self.waypoints.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([nameDescriptor]) as [OrderWaypoint]
    return sorted
}
```

Everything works as expected in the main target when using the following loop

```
for waypoint in order.getOrderedWaypoints() {
   // do something
}
```

But when I try the exact same thing in my test target

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

I've tried casting the values but can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas why it works in the main target but not the test target?

EDIT

Well breaking it down further, the issue is specifically happening when I try to get an item out of the array.

```
var orderedList: [OrderWaypoint] = order.getOrderedWaypoints()

for var i = 0; i < orderedList.count; i++ {
   var waypoint = orderedList[i]
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates the NSArray and passes it to Swift code?

Comment: I updated the original post with the method definition. order.waypoints is the NSSet in Core Data. I apply a sort descriptor to get an NSArray and downcast to [OrderWaypoint].

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm in a similar situation - using Core Data subclasses in a way that should work, but am running into this issue.

Comment: Also having the exact same problem. Any luck getting this to work???

Comment: I didn't find a way to fix it at the time, but switched to using an NSArray instead. I'd prefer not to do it this way, but I haven't had the time to look back into it. Sorry for the poor formatting below, but this is what we currently use.
`func getOrderedWaypoints() -> NSArray {
    let nameDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "stop_number", ascending: true)
    let sorted = self.waypoints.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([nameDescriptor])
    return sorted
}`

Answer (score 1):

You cant typecast as `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` returns a NSArray and you need to copy all elements from that array into the Swift Typed array.

```
func getOrderedWaypoints() -> [OrderWaypoint] {
    let nameDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "stop_number", ascending: true)
    let sorted = [OrderWaypoint]()
    for elem in self.waypoints.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([nameDescriptor]) {
        sorted.append(elem)
    }
    return sorted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do all that sorting in memory, I will generally have those helper methods that fetch related data get data directly from the database like:

```
var orderedWayPoints: [WayPoint] {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Waypoint")
    request.sortDescriptors = NSSortDescriptor(key: "stop_number", ascending: true)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parent = %@", self)

    return try! managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
}
```

The point is that I generally want the data base to do the grunt work of sorting my data rather that the code. And it's not much more code either.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the error is true: at least one of the elements in `self.waypoints` is not actually an `OrderWaypoint`. It is possible you have some other type in there that responds to the same messages. You may have a superclass of `OrderWaypoint` (are you using mogenerator, perhaps? are any of these actually `_OrderWaypoint` objects?) Are you swizzling the objects such that they lie about their true type? KVO can do this.

The fact that this fails in your test target raises the possibility that you're mocking these objects. Is that possible?

I'd start by carefully examining the contents of `self.waypoints` to make sure it actually contains what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it happens only in your test target is that it's a different module from your main application, so you get different versions of your `OrderWaypoint` class in each module, which Swift considers to be different classes: `App.OrderWaypoint` and `AppTest.OrderWaypoint`.

I'm working on solving this in my own project, and I'll update when I have a good solution :)

**Update:** For all-Swift projects, I think the solution is to remove your non-test .swift files from the test target, and add `@testable import YourAppModuleName` to your Swift tests. Apparently this is the modern approach and should probably be done anyway. (Though if your app is all Swift you probably won't have this problem.)

This did not work for me, though, because I have tests written in Objective-C that need to access my Swift classes, and I had trouble finding an Objective-C equivalent for importing the app target's Swift module.

My solution was to rewrite the problem code in Objective-C, where it doesn't do such strict type checking. In my case, that was easy because the problematic functions were in an extension on a class that's originally declared in Objective-C, so it's easy to move them over.

**Update 2:** A slightly underhanded but simpler solution is to remove the app Swift files from the test target, and then set the header search paths in the test target to point to the `DerivedSources` folder from the *app* target, and include the `App-Swift.h` file in the Objective-C tests that need it, instead of the `AppTest-Swift.h` file which no longer has the app Swift classes because you just removed them from the test target.

Comment: You for sure should not have source files in the test target, but you should not have to jimmy the header search path. Especially pointing to derived is ludicrous.

Comment: Well I'm open to alternatives. How else can an Objective-C source file get access to definitions for Swift classes from another target?

Comment: It's all described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). Pretty simple. Sorry if I sounded like a tool, I had my source files in test targets for years and finally broke myself of it.

Comment: I've gone over that page before. It talks about importing frameworks, but not importing from an app target to a test target.